# PATCH request to ModelViewSet in django rest framework - how do I implement serializer.update()?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement `PATCH` handling using a `ModelViewSet` for my Product API. (The Product instance primary key is a `uuid`, and hence the `uuid` appears as the `lookup_field` in the code below).

I'm confused about how to override the `update()` ModelSerializer class method. The stub in the source looks like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    raise NotImplementedError('`update()` must be implemented.')
```

I don't understand why `instance` and `validated_data` should be provided, because they should be properties of the serializer as per its instantiation:
`get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, many=False, partial=False)` (scroll up one paragraph [here in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins)). And why should I be providing the validated data? Isn't the serializer is supposed to validate it?

Here's my `partial_update()` implementation:

product.py (ViewSet class)

```
def get_object(self, uuid=None):
    """ Utility method to get the object """
    # authentication logic, returns None if object not found

def partial_update(self, request, uuid=None):
    instance = self.get_object(uuid)
    if not instance:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, 
                    data=request.data,
                    many=isinstance(request.data, list),
                    partial=True)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer.update() #NOT WORKING; NEEDS ARGS instance, validated_data
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # we link up the user foreign key here
    user=User.objects.filter(email=validated_data.pop('user', None)).first()
    if user:
        instance.fk_user = user

    #specify which fields to update, otherwise save() tries to SQL SET all fields
    update_fields = [k for k in validated_data]
    if user:
        update_fields.append('fk_user')
    for k,v in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, k, v)
    instance.save(update_fields=update_fields)
    return instance
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a good and sensible question.

The point is if `instance` and `validated_data` weren't provided, we'd have tons of questions about how to access them, plus some confusion with `create` vs `update` (they would have the same signature, why not make just one then).

**However, you should *not* call the serializer's `create` or `update` directly !!**

You just need to call `serializer.save()` and it'll perform the routing to either `create` or `update`

ie replace:

```
serializer.update() #NOT WORKING; NEEDS ARGS instance, validated_data
```

with

```
serializer.save()
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I guess I'll leave the design decisions to you smart people, but seeing that `validated_data` argument to the serializer really made me think "Wait ... whaaaat?" Thanks for the answer.